# WCF Message Body deserialization expects arbitrary namespace

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, deserialization

I have a WCF service that should be able to receive SOAP messages based on the HTNG/OTA publications (standards?). This publication contains a ton of .xsd files that I used to auto-generate classes (contracts?) from, [using Visual Studio's XSD as type definition feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjKvD.png).

This generated classes look like the following:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "15.5.180+ge4c819961e")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class OTA_HotelResNotifRQ
{ ... }
```

Then I set up a very simple service method that should receive a SOAP message containing an OTA_HotelResNotifRQ as payload, like:

```
// interface    
[OperationContract(Action = "OTA_HotelResNotifRQ", ReplyAction = "OTA_HotelResNotifRS")]
Message HotelResNotifRQ(Message input);

// implementation
public Message HotelResNotifRQ(Message input)
{
    var body = input.GetBody<OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>();
    // do something
}
```

When the GetBody<> is invoked it should deserialize the message's body, but ends up throwing an exception instead:

> Error in line 16 position 293. Expecting element 'OTA_HotelResNotifRQ'
>   from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Projects.Namespace'..
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name 'OTA_HotelResNotifRQ', namespace
>   'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'.

So I get a namespace mismatch, but where the heck does that arbitrary namespace of *schemas.datacontract.org* is coming from and why does it ignore the namespaces set in the Xml serialization attributes on the type (*OTA_HotelResNotifRQ*) itself?

How do I tell it that *OTA_HotelResNotifRQ* is indeed from the opentravel namespace?

Comment: You may need to deserialize manually using xml linq.  Or create a cutom serialize method where you can pass the url to the method.

Comment: It means you're deserializing using `DataContractSerializer` when you were expecting to use `XmlSerializer`.  You may need to apply `[XmlSerializerFormat]`.  See [Using the XmlSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class).

Comment: Writing XmlSerializerFormat attribute on my service contract and operation contract doesn't seem to change anything. When I get to the part where I would invoke GetBody<> on the Message it still uses the wrong serializer. How do I tell it to use XmlSerializer instead?
It does have an overload that expect a serializer, but does not accept XmlSerializer itself.